# Stored procedure return parameter

Tags: php, sql-server

The SQL guy wrote a stored procedure that is suppose to return a list of item that'd be affected by the request.

If I call the stored procedure within SQL Server Management Studio like the example below, I can see the list in a column named after the alias

```
DECLARE @RETURN_CLIENTS_SET nvarchar(max)
EXEC [dbo].[Sp_IHM_SET_FORMS_INDPROD_CLOSE_DATE]
    @Date = N'20171110',
    @RETURN_ITEMS = @RETURN_ITEMS OUTPUT

SELECT  @RETURN_ITEMS as N'@RETURN_ITEMS'
```

Now, If I try to show the result via a PHP like I'd do for a simple table fetch

```
$query_setdata = "DECLARE   @RETURN_CLIENTS_SET nvarchar(max)
EXEC [dbo].[Sp_IHM_SET_FORMS_INDPROD_CLOSE_DATE]
    @Date = N'20171110',
    @RETURN_ITEMS = @RETURN_ITEMS OUTPUT

SELECT  @RETURN_ITEMS as N'@RETURN_ITEMS'";
$prep_setdata = sqlsrv_prepare($conn, $query_setdata);

if(sqlsrv_execute($prep_setdata))
{
    while($data = sqlsrv_fetch_array($prep_setdata,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo $data['@RETURN_ITEMS'];
    }
}
else {
       die(print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

The stored procedure does its stuff in the database (changing some flags for certain items), I have no error, but it doesn't show the "RETURN_ITEMS" value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a batch like this:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @RETURN_ITEMS nvarchar(max);
EXEC [dbo].[Sp_IHM_SET_FORMS_INDPROD_CLOSE_DATE]
    @Date = N'20171110',
    @RETURN_ITEMS = @RETURN_ITEMS OUTPUT;

SELECT @RETURN_ITEMS as RETURN_ITEMS;
```

The row count messages confuse some client drivers.  The resultset column name should be an ordinary identifier, and the local variable you declare needs to be the one you return.  And it can have the same name as the stored proc output parameter.